# Blazor SignalR 20K max message reached

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I was developing my Blazor server app locally and suddenly it stopped loading. The error message is "the server responded with a status of 500 ()". Looking at the log, the detailed error was "Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.ServiceConnection: Critical: Service returned handshake error: Maximum message count limit reached: 20000".

The app was deployed to Azure once from Visual Studio. During publish, I've added a signalR service as a dependency and Azure created a signalR service. It is this service that's in a free tier which has a 20K message per day limit.

I don't quite understand how localhost work with remote Azure signalR service ... why is my local development depends on Azure service during dev? The app I published to Azure is using the same signalR service and is working just fine. Only my local fails.

Can someone please help me understand this? I mean before I published to Azure, I didn't even have an Azure account, how did it work back then? Is there any way to remove my local dependency to it so I can freely develop without such limitation.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You only really need to use Azure SignalR for scale - remove the call in startup that says AddAzureSignalR() or wrap it with a preprocessor directive so it is only used in Release builds.

```cs
#if RELEASE
services.AddAzureSignalR();
#endif
```

To enable the use of a RELEASE flag, you want to define a RELEASE constant for the release configuration in csproj:

```xml
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants)TRACE;RELEASE</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: I did remove this line, and yet my local environment is still trying to connect to remote signalr service. Something else I am missing?

Comment: I can only guess - did you do a full clean / build in case something didn't rebuild? Did you restart VS in case it has something cached? Move the Azure credentials to a Release configuration file so that Debug configuration cannot connect?